# Iterating through a csv file in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am new to jmeter and I want to run a single test multiple times using the same csv file.

I just wanted to know if jmeter continues from where it stopped reading the csv file for when i run the test again.

Eg: lets say I ran the test the first time and it read 300 rows from the csv file. now when i run the test again, does jmeter automatically start to pick up data from the 301st row in the csv file? If not, how will I be able to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Jmeter will start form the first row again if you stop the test and start it again.

You can add an [aggregate report listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) and check how many iteration were made after stopping the test, then remove the rows which has been used from your CSV file and start the test.